# C open() returns -1 for a path string

Tags: c, path, directory, system-calls

when i use open() as

```
int ff=open("/home/user/desktop/bla/test",O_RDONLY);
```

it works fine.

but when i use a string as the (same path stored in a string) path it doesn't work.

```
int ff=open(string,O_RDONLY);
```

why is this?

this is my whole code. i'm confused. i know it should work. but i doesn't. i can't find the bug.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

void bla(char *);
int main(void)
{
// int i;
FILE * fp=fopen("path","r");
char line[256];

while( fgets(line,255,fp)!=NULL){

bla(line);

 }

return 0;
}


void bla(char * line){

int status;
printf("%s",line);


pid_t pid=fork();

char string[256];
if(pid==0){

    pid=wait(&status);

    int ff=open(line,O_RDONLY);

    if(ff<0){
        printf("\topen error!\n\n");
    return;}

    int ret=read(ff,string,255);

    if(ret<0){
        printf("read error!\n");
    return;}

    printf("%s",string);
close(ff);

exit(0);


}   
if (pid>0){
        return;
}
 }
```

in bla function, if i replace 'line' with the path, it works. i used a printf to make sure. path is the same (it seems the same).

Comment: Can you also show how 'string' is defined and initialized?  Perhaps: char *string="/home/user/desktop/bla/test"   ???

Comment: try to print `errno` using `strerror`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call shenanigans :-)

Obviously, if `string` were exactly the same value as your string literal, and all others things remained the same, it would work fine.

So, *if* all other things are the same, `string` is obviously *not* set to the value you think it is, to wit `"/home/user/desktop/bla/test"`.

My advice would be to print it out (along with an error string) to be sure, something like:

```
fprintf (stderr, "DEBUG: string is [%s]\n", string);
int ff = open (string, O_RDONLY);
if (ff < 0)
    perror ("Could not open file");
```

---

And, now that you've posted the code, your problem is obvious: `fgets()` does not remove the trailing newline so, were you to add the code I proposed above, you would see:

```
DEBUG: string is [/home/user/desktop/bla/test
]
```

and deduce the problem.

A quick way to fix this is to remove the newline yourself, with something like:

```
while (fgets (line, 255, fp) != NULL) {
    size_t ln = strlen (line);             // Add these
    if ((ln > 0) && (line[ln-1] == '\n'))  //   three
        line[ln-1] = '\0';                 //   lines.
    bla (line);
}
```

Comment: @udakarajd, thanks for posting the code. The problem lies with the fact `fgets` preserves the trailing newline. See the updated answer.